# Specify an exception or not?

Tags: java, performance, exception, try-catch

i have a little performance question, when working with a try catch clause, it's better to specify the exact exception you can get or just using exception it's better?
Example:

```
try {
    whatever
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    whatever
}
```

or if you don't mind what kind of exception:

```
try {
    whatever
} catch (Exception ex) {
    whatever
}
```

Because i know that you can use different exceptions to trigger different effects, but i'm just asking for performance.

Comment: My guess would be that the performance is the same, except in the case of catching a `Throwable`, as anything more specific than that will require the program to check the `Throwable`'s type.  This is just a guess, though.

Comment: Why don't you try to benchmark it yourself and post the results here.

Comment: @anubhava Because every time I attempt to benchmark something I'm told that I do not benchmark properly.  Haha :)

Comment: "if you don't mind what kind of exception" <-- you should always mind. Note also that `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception; generally, you should not catch these except if you know what you are doing

Comment: Before determining the performance try-catch clause, you should read a little of Exceptions theory, please check this links: 
1) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/
2) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html
3) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1375121/1563878.
Its important that you understand the differencesbetween Unchecked and checked exceptions.

Comment: Exception catching is *NOT* where you want to play with optimization. You want to be as specific as possible so that debugging can easy.

Comment: One thing I forgot to say is that you should not catch unchecked exceptions, in this case an NullPointerException, is not a good practice. So following your example you should catch only a Exception

Comment: @GastonF: It depends on the context. Catching a `RuntimeException`s is *often* a bad idea, because it's a sign of a deeper problem (a code smell), but not always. I often find situations where it makes sense to catch a `NumberFormatException`, for example.

Comment: @TomAnderson good point, in these cases if correct catch such exceptions, I express bad, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

According to my tests, there is **no significant difference in performance**.

Each run attempts ten million of each scenario and then compares the run times in nanoseconds as well as rounded seconds.  This is actually contrary to my original hypothesis, as I thought that catching a `Throwable` would show a marked improvement.

I also began to realize that part of this may be due to the optimizer's influence, and so I have created a more convoluted example which includes pseudo-random numbers below, thinking that this will mitigate any potential influence the optimizer is having on the code.

(I won't lecture you about proper use of `catch` blocks, as the question is specifically about *performance*, not best practices.)

***Lots of Data Below This Point!***

**Run 1 Results:**

```
Exception: 7196141955 (7.196s)
NumberFormatException: 7736401837 (7.736s)
Throwable: 6818656505 (6.819s)
```

**Run 2 Results:**

```
Exception: 7262897545 (7.263s)
NumberFormatException: 7056116050 (7.056s)
Throwable: 7108232206 (7.108s)
```

**Run 3 Results:**

```
Exception: 7088967045 (7.089s)
NumberFormatException: 7020495455 (7.020s)
Throwable: 7192925684 (7.193s)
```

**Run 4 Results:**

```
Exception: 6916917328 (6.917s)
NumberFormatException: 7690084994 (7.690s)
Throwable: 6906011513 (6.906s)
```

**Run 5 Results:**

```
Exception: 7247571874 (7.248s)
NumberFormatException: 6818511040 (6.819s)
Throwable: 6813286603 (6.813s)
```

**Code**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Test {

    private static final int TRIALS = 10000000;
    private static final int NANOS_IN_SECOND = 1000000000;
    private static final int DECIMAL_PRECISION = 3;
    private static final RoundingMode ROUNDING_MODE = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long firstStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }

        long firstEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long secondStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }

        long secondEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long thirdStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
            catch(Throwable e) {

            }
        }

        long thirdEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long exception = firstEnd - firstStart;
        long numberFormatException = secondEnd - secondStart;
        long throwable = thirdEnd - thirdStart;

        BigDecimal exceptionSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)exception / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);
        BigDecimal numberFormatExceptionSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)numberFormatException / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);
        BigDecimal throwableSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)throwable / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);

        exceptionSeconds = exceptionSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);
        numberFormatExceptionSeconds = numberFormatExceptionSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);
        throwableSeconds = throwableSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);

        System.out.println("Exception: " + exception + " (" + exceptionSeconds + "s)");
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + numberFormatException + " (" + numberFormatExceptionSeconds + "s)");
        System.out.println("Throwable: " + throwable + " (" + throwableSeconds + "s)");

    }

}
```

**More Convoluted, Pseudo-Random Code**

I created this in order to make sure the optimizer wasn't simply "ignoring" the entire throw/catch process by realizing that the code block will always flow through to the `catch`.  By attempting an `Integer.parseInt()` on a randomly-selected `String` (but always an invalid one), this means the compiler can't know until runtime whether a given run through the `for()` loops is valid or not.

As expected from the first experiment, there is no significant difference between the three scenarios.

**Run 1 Results:**

```
Exception: 10988431371 (10.988s)
NumberFormatException: 11360698958 (11.361s)
Throwable: 10539041505 (10.539s)
```

**Run 2 Results:**

```
Exception: 12468860076 (12.469s)
NumberFormatException: 11852429194 (11.852s)
Throwable: 11859547560 (11.860s)
```

**Run 3 Results:**

```
Exception: 10618082779 (10.618s)
NumberFormatException: 10718252324 (10.718s)
Throwable: 10327709072 (10.328s)
```

**Run 4 Results:**

```
Exception: 11031135405 (11.031s)
NumberFormatException: 10689877480 (10.690s)
Throwable: 10668345685 (10.668s)
```

**Run 5 Results:**

```
Exception: 11513727192 (11.514s)
NumberFormatException: 11581826079 (11.582s)
Throwable: 12488301109 (12.488s)
```

**Code**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    private static final int TRIALS = 10000000;
    private static final int NANOS_IN_SECOND = 1000000000;
    private static final int DECIMAL_PRECISION = 3;
    private static final RoundingMode ROUNDING_MODE = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;

    private static final String[] TEST_STRINGS = {
        "lawl",
        "rofl",
        "trololo",
        "foo",
        "bar"
    };

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long firstStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(TEST_STRINGS[RANDOM.nextInt(TEST_STRINGS.length)]);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }

        long firstEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long secondStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(TEST_STRINGS[RANDOM.nextInt(TEST_STRINGS.length)]);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }

        long secondEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long thirdStart = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < TRIALS; i++) {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(TEST_STRINGS[RANDOM.nextInt(TEST_STRINGS.length)]);
            }
            catch(Throwable e) {

            }
        }

        long thirdEnd = System.nanoTime();

        long exception = firstEnd - firstStart;
        long numberFormatException = secondEnd - secondStart;
        long throwable = thirdEnd - thirdStart;

        BigDecimal exceptionSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)exception / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);
        BigDecimal numberFormatExceptionSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)numberFormatException / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);
        BigDecimal throwableSeconds = new BigDecimal((double)throwable / (double)NANOS_IN_SECOND);

        exceptionSeconds = exceptionSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);
        numberFormatExceptionSeconds = numberFormatExceptionSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);
        throwableSeconds = throwableSeconds.setScale(DECIMAL_PRECISION, ROUNDING_MODE);

        System.out.println("Exception: " + exception + " (" + exceptionSeconds + "s)");
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + numberFormatException + " (" + numberFormatExceptionSeconds + "s)");
        System.out.println("Throwable: " + throwable + " (" + throwableSeconds + "s)");

    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for efforts to write this benchmark and trust me it seems to be proper benchmarking :P

Comment: Thanks for all that testing, that greatly helps me :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the correct answer here is to use the appropriate exception handling per programmatic reasons as opposed to performance. If (ignoring performance) it would be more appropriate to catch a `NullPointerException` then do that.

Exceptions are supposed to be the exceptional case. They should happen rarely therefor performance in exception processing should be less important than correctness.

If your application is anticipating this situation regularly then it should handle it via some mechanism other than an Exception. This is especially true if you are worried about performance because throwing exceptions is ALWAYS expensive.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, neither. try/catch is comparatively expensive and should be used sparingly. You are better off manually checking for null than catching a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is in any way relevant in terms of exception catching, it's not an exception.

All it's doing is an is test so I doubt it makes any real difference.

Catching Exception should be very rare anyway.

If you were doing

```
try 
{
    whatever
} 
catch (MyException10 ex10) 
{
    whatever
}
catch (MyException9 ex9) 
{
    whatever
}
...
catch (MyException1 ex1) 
{
    whatever
}
```

Then you could argue a potential performance improvement, but that would be rework your code so one bit didn't throw umpteen exceptions...

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in the exception-catching process in general and if Java would treat catching `Exception` differently than catching `MoreSpecificException`.

Comment: Sometimes one may be stuck using an API where it's impossible to avoid throwing lots of exceptions. As an example, one may have a dictionary-ish interface which includes a "get item" method that throws if the item doesn't exist, but includes no other means of testing whether an item exists. The fact that such an interface may be poorly designed doesn't necessarily make it possible to change it. In such cases, exception-handling performance may be very important.

Comment: It would to be one heck of an inheritance tree and you'd need to be throwing exceptions a lot. In which case they are not exceptional. If you get stuffed with an API as mentioned by supercat, may be, but I'd be looking at ways round that not messing about trying to handle them more efficiently. The cost of the is a test is trivial compared to the actual exception itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best performance advice for try/catch block that I can come up with is: make them small.

If you have a piece of code that can throw, say, three exceptions, do:

```
try {
    piece1();
} catch (Exception1 e) {
    // whatever
}

try {
    piece2();
} catch (Exception2 e) {
    // whatever
}

try {
    piece3();
} catch (Exception3 e) {
    // whatever
}
```

This way, you can `return`/`break`/`continue` early. And treat each exception the way it is meant to be treated. It is rare that you "do not mind" what exception is caught.

Note also that an overly broad `catch` block may "hide" exceptions which you do not expect could be thrown. In particular, all `RuntimeException`s are caught when you catch `Exception` (and that includes `NullPointerException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and other niceties). And this is Not Good(tm).