# Android JSONTokener - Nullpointer exception at nextCleanInternal not being caught

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, parse-platform

I am going through a JSONObject in my onCreate() method. It is surrounded in an try/catch block that I had thought would catch all exceptions, but it appears that a nullpointerexception is still being encountered and crashes the app. I have checks in place to ensure that that the string I am searching for in the object is not null/empty, and I am not sure how else to protect from the exception. Code and stack trace are as follows:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        JSONObject notificationData;
        try {
            notificationData = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("com.parse.Data"));
            if(notificationData.getString("targetUrl") != null && !notificationData.getString("targetUrl").equals("")){
                //do stuff
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
notificationData = new JSONObject(bundle.getString("com.parse.Data"));
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.Test/com.example.Test.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
at com.example.Test.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:293)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

I am not too experienced with using JSONObjects in Java/Android. What can I do to prevent this nullpointer from occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to catch a NPE is not really recommended.

I'm assuming that your code crashes because `bundle.getString("com.parse.Data")` is actually `null`.

I would suggest to check for `null`, so change it like this:

```
if (bundle != null && bundle.getString("com.parse.Data") != null)
```

This would avoid the NPE you are getting. In case you do manage to get the String out of the bundle, you might still encounter other exceptions when attempting to build the `JSONObject`. Can not help you with that, need to see more of the code.

Comment: I had thought that the try/catch function would catch any nullpointerexception found. So, even if `bundle.getString("com.parse.Data")` is null, it's inside the `try` block when the exception is thrown. So I THOUGHT that meant it would be caught and I could handle it accordingly. I've added your suggestion and will try it out to see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: NPE is a Runtime exception. To better understand what you can and cannot catch, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375113/java-exception-not-caught. It is explained better.